# Pjax History don't work - is it just me?

Tags: pjax, history.js

when checking the PJAX live demo - http://padrino-pjax.heroku.com/
The history (back button) don't work! 
I can not find any documentation about it, it seems useless if it craps the history functionality.

Can anyone tell me if this is how it should be?

What I did to check was go through the 3 links (don't forget to check the "use PJAX" box)
then clicking back and seeing it went to the first one instead of the second.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

it's works fine. you need to enable it first via checkbox ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check the original code, what you posted is a porting of the original demo founded here: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/tree/heroku